# Why am I getting the message 'Youractivity.java is not an activity subclass or alias'

Tags: android, android-activity, subclass

I created my own Android project and cut and pasted the code from this exercise:

http://androidexample.com/Show_Phone_Contacts_In_AutoComplete_Suggestions_-_Android_Example%20/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=106&aaid=128#

When I build the project I get no errors or warnings. When I run the project I get this window with an error:

[image]

Annoyingly, I can't make the window any smaller, so I can't click any of the buttons. I just cick the 'X' at the top, to close it.

Here's my project structure:

[image]

Where is it getting 'AutocompleteMain' from? (note the small c) My class is named AutoCompleteMain. Thanks for any help.

And I do have the activity included in my Android Manifest, in case you're wondering:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.androidexample.autocompleteedittext"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.chris.dialler.AutoCompleteMain"
            android:label="@string/app_name"  >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

And here's the code of my class, AutoCompleteMain.java :

(one thing I notice, in this class, is that phoneNumber.toString() and name.toString() are highlighted, saying they're redundant. Don't know if that's the cause of the problem)

```
package com.example.chris.dialler;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import com.androidexample.autocompleteedittext.R;

public class AutoCompleteMain extends Activity implements  OnItemClickListener, OnItemSelectedListener  {

    // Initialize variables

    AutoCompleteTextView textView=null;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    // Store contacts values in these arraylist
    public static ArrayList<String> phoneValueArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> nameValueArr = new ArrayList<String>();

    EditText toNumber=null;
    String toNumberValue="";


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);

        setContentView(R.layout.autocomplete_main);

        final Button Send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Send);

        // Initialize AutoCompleteTextView values

        textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.toNumber);

        //Create adapter
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, new ArrayList<String>());
        textView.setThreshold(1);

        //Set adapter to AutoCompleteTextView
        textView.setAdapter(adapter);
        textView.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        textView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        // Read contact data and add data to ArrayAdapter
        // ArrayAdapter used by AutoCompleteTextView

        readContactData();


        /********** Button Click pass textView object ***********/
        Send.setOnClickListener(BtnAction(textView));


    }

    private OnClickListener BtnAction(final AutoCompleteTextView toNumber) {
        return new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                String NameSel = "";
                NameSel = toNumber.getText().toString();


                final String ToNumber = toNumberValue;


                if (ToNumber.length() == 0 ) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please fill phone number",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), NameSel+" : "+toNumberValue,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        };
    }


    // Read phone contact name and phone numbers

    private void readContactData() {

        try {

            /*********** Reading Contacts Name And Number **********/

            String phoneNumber = "";
            ContentResolver cr = getBaseContext()
                    .getContentResolver();

            //Query to get contact name

            Cursor cur = cr
                    .query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            null,
                            null,
                            null);

            // If data data found in contacts
            if (cur.getCount() > 0) {

                Log.i("AutocompleteContacts", "Reading   contacts........");

                int k=0;
                String name = "";

                while (cur.moveToNext())
                {

                    String id = cur
                            .getString(cur
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    name = cur
                            .getString(cur
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                    //Check contact have phone number
                    if (Integer
                            .parseInt(cur
                                    .getString(cur
                                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0)
                    {

                        //Create query to get phone number by contact id
                        Cursor pCur = cr
                                .query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                        null,
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                                + " = ?",
                                        new String[] { id },
                                        null);
                        int j=0;

                        while (pCur
                                .moveToNext())
                        {
                            // Sometimes get multiple data
                            if(j==0)
                            {
                                // Get Phone number
                                phoneNumber =""+pCur.getString(pCur
                                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                                // Add contacts names to adapter
                                adapter.add(name);

                                // Add ArrayList names to adapter
                                phoneValueArr.add(phoneNumber.toString());
                                nameValueArr.add(name.toString());

                                j++;
                                k++;
                            }
                        }  // End while loop
                        pCur.close();
                    } // End if

                }  // End while loop

            } // End Cursor value check
            cur.close();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("AutocompleteContacts","Exception : "+ e);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                               long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Log.d("AutocompleteContacts", "onItemSelected() position " + position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(
                INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // Get Array index value for selected name
        int i = nameValueArr.indexOf(""+arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2));

        // If name exist in name ArrayList
        if (i >= 0) {

            // Get Phone Number
            toNumberValue = phoneValueArr.get(i);

            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(
                    INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);

            // Show Alert
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "Position:"+arg2+" Name:"+arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2)+" Number:"+toNumberValue,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Log.d("AutocompleteContacts",
                    "Position:"+arg2+" Name:"+arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2)+" Number:"+toNumberValue);

        }

    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Does my question look unclear to you? Spent two hours researching and trying to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

phoneNumber and name are already Strings so there it is, and unnecessary, to try and convert them to Strings. In regards to your main question, I have had annoying problems like this in the past and I would either try syncing gradle or rebooting Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide the code of that class? Does it extend any type of Activity? From the looks of your manifest, it is set as your launching activity. You have to make sure it isn't just a plain Java class. It needs to be a type of activity (FragmentActivity, Activity, CombatActivity, etc....) Let me know if this helps!

Comment: phoneNumber and name are already Strings so there it is, and unnecessary, to try and convert them to Strings. In regards to your main question, I have had annoying problems like this in the past and I would either try syncing gradle or rebooting Android Studio.

Comment: Hm. Weird. I restarted Android Studio and now it works. If you put that comment in an answer I'll mark it as the correct one, thanks.